# PHP - cURL not outputting XML data

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl

As per the title, I'm using cURL to connect up to my webservice which should then output the response in XML format. cURL is enabled on the server as per my check, however it isn't displaying anything in the response of `$xml`.

```
define('SERVICE_URL', 'http://www.myurl.com/webservices/users');
define('USERNAME', 'user');
define('PASSWORD', 'pass');
//define('KEY', 'YOUR_KEY/SID_HERE');

$post = array(
        'UserID' => '5',
        'Name' => 'John',   
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, SERVICE_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
echo $xml;
```

Comment: Have you checked for curl errors?

Comment: @cale_b: I've only checked if it's enabled and it is. I'll try `if(curl_errno($c))...` now.

Comment: does it really return valid xml data? kindly check errors on logs.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server so no error logs. But yes it should return valid xml data as per the documentation displaying a valid xml response.

Comment: Also try dumping your raw results

Comment: @cale_b Thanks I'm going to dump `$result` shortly and let you know what is returned.

Comment: @cale_b Ok now it's not outputting anything but "Server Error 
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." and the credentials and definitely correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that $result is actually giving you a result.  If it isn't, then your problem isn't with SimpleXMLElement, it's with your curl call.

Second, create an HTML form that sends your data to your URL and check to see that it's actually sending data back.  If you aren't getting data, then the problem is with the service, not your curl calls.

Finally, if you're getting data in $result, then check for exceptions in your SimpleXMLElement call:

```
try {
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
}
catch( Exception $e ) {
  echo "found an exception: " . $e;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CullyLarson I'll give this a go shortly and advise :)

Comment: Also, make sure that error reporting is on error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: Thanks, will make sure of it!

Comment: Ok now it's not outputting anything but "Server Error 
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." and the credentials and definitely correct.